# Python/Requests POST with multiple authentication tokens

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm trying to do a single POST to multiple accounts. I have a list of the authentication tokens to each account but can't seem to get the program to cycle through the tokens to post each one.

I've tried using the list as the bearer token, but it simply doesn't post anything to any accounts. I'm not sure how to make the session run multiple times.

```
token = "875152GTmm6ReRLZZJjq1cXdw2nCSMSln9Rl6dsak9Kz4oMqVecXzXCcdnPTz29zYOGO4GewawDftSc.bz-VQ459HFz9rH80l71oqhyblIi6yp8NzXZ.iEYV5zNbT8.hd"
token2 = "WzQSLogJvtZfGFX5uzgC.8aK80uqlWIb.o0MReU8wJvo-Y3INsM3DYD86bkjqynKqrdlDZLBsK9N64WC2kPNkziIPoCCMQh4ahp4.JVUz4jkfLwNgLVf9pwG2KtRDWHr"
token3 = "fV6FpCU2U70pySDimYcPZC2NpEhxfCEjJVh5XjhbQ7pBqYZRwyY2NGU3.VVd8N-clTQAqJjOa19h7zkEQ3oitTKkyvpJR8zGoBxWgdbCNuVcwwxwrnBaz-gO6Zht4Xxh"

token_list = [token2, token3]


s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({
  "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token_list,
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
})

payloadt1 = {
    "title": "NPS/Marketing Example",
    "from_template_id": "293"
}
payloadt2 = {
    "title": "HR - Exit Interview",
    "from_template_id": "359"
}
payloadt3 = {
    "title": "Market Research - Product Testing",
    "from_template_id": "319"
}
payloadt4 = {
    "title": "New Hire Training (Quiz)",
    "from_template_id": "1234"
}

url = "https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys"
s.post(url, json=payloadt1)
s.post(url, json=payloadt2)
s.post(url, json=payloadt3)
s.post(url, json=payloadt4)

I get no error from running the program, but no templates appear in the accounts.
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that `requests.Session()` includes cookies and other authentication elements, you should create a separate session for every account you use for example:

```
s1 = requests.Session()
s2 = requests.Session()
s3 = requests.Session()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being just a simple fix:

```
              "fV6FpCU2U70pySDimYcPZC2NpEhxfCEjJVh5XjhbQ7pBqYZRwyY2NGU3.VVd8N-clTQAqJjOa19h7zkEQ3oitTKkyvpJR8zGoBxWgdbCNuVcwwxwrnBaz-gO6Zht4Xxh"]

for token in token_list:
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers.update({
        "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
```